# Writing a formatted string to a file - Java

Tags: java, string, format, bufferedwriter, printstream

I have a string that I format with the `System.out.format()` method, I do something like :

```
System.out.format("I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar);
```

but when I try to write this formatted string into a file, I only get something like `"java.io.PrintStream@84fc8d"` in it.

After looking into the documentation understood that this method is a little like `System.out.print()` and just return a PrintStream to display (in console for example), so I tried converting it with `.toString` or `String.valueOf()` but I get the same result.

So I was wondering if there is a way to format a string just like the `String.out.format()` method does, but in a way that will be writable in a file ?

Here is approximately the code I use (just making the useful parts appear)

```
WRITE_MY_LINE(System.out.format(" I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar).toString());
//also tried this :
WRITE_MY_LINE(String.valueOf(System.out.format(" I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar)));

public static void WRITE_MY_LINE(String line) {
        buff_out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(ascii_path, true));

        buff_out.append(line);
        buff_out.newLine();
        buff_out.flush();
}
```

Comment: Override `Object#toString` in your variable's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**String.format**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is what you are looking for it returns a `String` and not a `PrintStream` like `System.out.format`.

Your code should be:

```
WRITE_MY_LINE(String.format(" I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar));
```

Take a look at **[Java.lang.String.format() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_format.htm)** for further information.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.format` returns `PrintStream` `Object` and `toString` method call is giving you `java.io.PrintStream@84fc8d` which you are trying to write.

You should use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) instead.

***i.e***

```
WRITE_MY_LINE(String.format(" I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
WRITE_MY_LINE(String.format(" I = %3d  var = %9.6f", i, myVar));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use java.util.Formatter from java 7 . refer documentation:

[java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)